# How to get the mysql values as jquery array value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a problem with my code, I want set values from database(mysql) to jquery array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {4:"BMW",14:"FORD",24:"MAZDA",34:"PEUGOT",44:"HONDA",54:"KIA",64:"CHEVROLET"}
  
  $("#module").keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#items").val(data[val]);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="module" name="module">

<input type="text" id="items" name="items" value="" disabled>
```

In the code above I used a direct approach however the list of values on the array would reach more than a thousand entries, is it possible to get the data from database instead? Though I'm not really familiar on how to get through with this issue. I'm thinking of changing the above code of array to the below to extract the database value as jquery value

```
 var data = {$module[]:$items[]}
```

Hope someone can help on this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: 
1. Fetch values from DB using PHP
2. Use it in jQuery like var records = '<?php echo $records;?>';

Answer (score 0):

You can have table which will store your values as you have in array above and then you can make normal ajax call on keyup event which will make db search based on input and will return data accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the idea will check on that and see if I can work something out of it